# How fast do the "partial sums of $\zeta(it)$" grow for fixed $t \neq 0$?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, upper-lower-bounds

In analytic number theory there are bounds for these partial sums, for example
$$
  \sum_{n \leq x} n^{-it} = O(x^{1/2} t^{\varepsilon})
$$
for $ |t| \geq x^{1/2} $ (so square root cancellation happens here as long as |t| is sufficiently large). But does it still hold when $t \neq 0$ is fixed and x goes to $\infty$? Is there something known about the growth of
$
  \sum_{n \leq x} n^{-it}
$
for fixed $t \neq 0$ as $x \to \infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior as $x\to \infty$ is much easier, simply use $$\sum_{n\le x} n^{-it} = \sum_{n\le x} \int_n^{n+1}( x^{-it}+n^{-it}-x^{-it})dx=\sum_{n\le x} \int_n^{n+1}( x^{-it}+\int_n^x it y^{-it-1}dy)dx$$ $$=
\sum_{n\le x} \int_n^{n+1}( x^{-it}+it x^{-it-1}+O(t^2 x^{-it-2}))dx = \frac{x^{1-it}}{1-it}+O(1+t^2)$$

Comment: Thank you! I don't think this double integral is necessary. Using $n^{-it} - x^{-it} = O(t/n)$ for $x \in [n, n+1]$ gives the same result with the error term $O(t \log(x))$.